# overflow-x hide ::before element

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am trying to display written information in markdown. At the time of showing the code I would like to show the programming language used by means of an image in a before.

But trying to do that and triggering overflow-x: auto; y overflow-y: visible; It keeps hiding the image from me. If I remove the overflow:auto; if it shows the picture.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.remark-code-title {
  background-color: rgb(192 132 252);
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: 600;
}

pre.language-js::before {
  background: url("https://riverscode.vercel.app/assets/javascript.png");
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 0;
  top: -15px;
  left: 10px;
}

.markdown-body pre {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  padding: 16px;
  word-break: break-all;
  font-size: 85%;
  line-height: 1.45;
  background-color: #161b22;
  color: red;
  /* Problem with activate overflow-x */
  overflow-y: visible;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/styles.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="markdown-body">

    <div class="remark-code-title">callbacks.js</div>
    <pre class="language-js"><code class="language-js"><span class="token keyword">function</span> <span class="token function"><span class="token maybe-class-name">UseHability</span></span><span class="token punctuation">(</span><span class="token parameter">fruitName</span><span class="token punctuation">)</span> <span class="token punctuation">{</span>
        <span class="token console class-name">console</span><span class="token punctuation">.</span><span class="token method function property-access">log</span><span class="token punctuation">(</span><span class="token template-string"><span class="token template-punctuation string">`</span><span class="token string">Puedes usar el poder de </span><span class="token interpolation"><span class="token interpolation-punctuation punctuation">${</span>fruitName<span class="token interpolation-punctuation punctuation">}</span></span><span class="token template-punctuation string">`</span></span><span class="token punctuation">)</span><span class="token punctuation">;</span>
        <span class="token punctuation">}</span>
        
        <span class="token keyword">function</span> <span class="token function"><span class="token maybe-class-name">EatFruit</span></span><span class="token punctuation">(</span><span class="token parameter">fruitName<span class="token punctuation">,</span> callback</span><span class="token punctuation">)</span> <span class="token punctuation">{</span>
            <span class="token console class-name">console</span><span class="token punctuation">.</span><span class="token method function property-access">log</span><span class="token punctuation">(</span><span class="token template-string"><span class="token template-punctuation string">`</span><span class="token string">He comido la fruta </span><span class="token interpolation"><span class="token interpolation-punctuation punctuation">${</span>fruitName<span class="token interpolation-punctuation punctuation">}</span></span><span class="token template-punctuation string">`</span></span><span class="token punctuation">)</span><span class="token punctuation">;</span>
            <span class="token function">callback</span><span class="token punctuation">(</span><span class="token punctuation">)</span><span class="token punctuation">;</span>
            <span class="token punctuation">}</span>
            
            <span class="token function"><span class="token maybe-class-name">EatFruit</span></span><span class="token punctuation">(</span><span class="token string">"mera mera no mi"</span><span class="token punctuation">,</span> <span class="token maybe-class-name">UseHability</span><span class="token punctuation">)</span><span class="token punctuation">;</span>
        </code></pre>
    </div>
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```